# How can I assign the type to a macro-defined number?

Tags: c, macros

In general, I kind of understand how integer literals work within macros. So if I wanted to define something as an `unsigned long` within a macro I would produce the following code:

`#define CLOCK_FREQUENCY 16000000UL`

That's my general understanding of integer literals.

What I am aiming to do however, is designate a number as `uint32_t` inside of my macro. In trying to find a way to do this, I haven't discovered any integer literals that would correspond to `uint32_t`. So, is there a way to actually designate a number as a `uint32_t` or other type (for that matter) not available by integer literal notation?

Comment: `uint32_t` is not a "built-in" c type, so it doesn't have specific built-in suffixes or literals having this type.

Comment: @Snoopy, Although defining a number to a specific type is often useful, I have found it often masks a higher level problem.  Knowing code's need for this type, answers could address such concerns.

Comment: Note that casts in macro `#if` processioning have nil effect.  With `#if CLOCK_FREQUENCY  ...`, the value is still type 64-bit (or more) then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I assign the type to a macro-defined number?

For `uint32_t`, use a cast as well answered by [@dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335858/dasblinkenlight)

---

There are pitfalls to casting.

A cast may *narrow* the constant as below when `unsigned` is 16-bit.   A cast may not generate a warnings about this as the compiler assumes the programmer is correct.

```
// Becomes  9216 on a 16-bit `unsigned.
#define CLOCK_FREQUENCY ((unsigned) 16000000)
```

---

C with `<stdint.h>` provides *Macros for minimum-width integer constants*.  I find the `((uint32_t)16000000)` preferable

The below results in a `uint_least32_t`, which is commonly the same as `uint32_t`.

```
UINT32_C(16000000)
```

---

When a type that is needed to accommodate the constant, often a cast is not used.

```
#define CLOCK_FREQUENCY 16000000U
```

When a specific type is needed, casting is a good idea.

```
#define CLOCK_FREQUENCY ((uint32_t) 16000000U)
```

When a type is needed that is *at least* the width of a type, be more gentile.

```
#define FOO 16000000000U
#define CLOCK_FREQUENCY (((uint32_t) 1) * FOO)
```

---

Notes:

In C, `16000000UL` is not a *literal*, but a *constant*.  *Literals* can have their address taken.

Further, the `L` in `16000000UL` only serves to widen a constant, in this case to at least `unsigned long`.  With a  `long` as a 64-bit, this widening may not be needed.
 `16000000U` is sufficient to form  a constant as wide as needed.

`UL` does not force the constant to be `unsigned long`, but only *at least* `unsigned long`.   `16000000000UL` may be type `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 2):

The standard provides macros for that job in `<stdint.h>`:

> #### [C11 7.20.4.1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.4.1) Macros for minimum-width integer constants
>
> ¶1 The macro `INTN_C(value)` shall expand to an integer constant expression
>   corresponding to the type `int_leastN_t`. The macro `UINTN_C(value)` shall expand
>   to an integer constant expression corresponding to the type `uint_leastN_t`. For
>   example, if `uint_least64_t` is a name for the type `unsigned long long int`,
>   then `UINT64_C(0x123)` might expand to the integer constant `0x123ULL`.

That means you could write:

```
#define CLOCK_FREQUENCY UINT32_C(16000000)
```

The advantage is that `uint_least32_t` is guaranteed to exist where `uint32_t` is not guaranteed to exist.  The downside is that `uint_least32_t` might not be the same type as `uint32_t` (but that can only happen if there is no `uint32_t`, so your code might not fail to compile on account of your constant even though it would if you managed to use `uint32_t` directly.  I suppose you could tinker with `(uint32_t)UINT32_C(16000000)`, but that seems like a serious case of overkill.

Comment: Aside: I find `UINTN_C(value)` sometimes a surprise  when `N` < `int/unsigned` bit width .  `UINT8_C(42)` may result in a `unsigned/uint32_t` type and not an `unint8_t`.  Further the sign-ness is not assured.  I'd, at first, expect `printf("%d\n", (UINT8_C(-5)) < 0  );` to be false.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a macro that includes the cast to the desired type, like this:

```
#define CLOCK_FREQUENCY ((uint32_t)16000000)
```

This lets you avoid integer literal notation altogether.

Comment: I always thought a cast could only be executed at run-time, so I didn't see that as an option. Thank you.

Comment: @Snoopy Macros just cause simple text substitution, so the cast will notionally occur wherever the macro is expanded. More generally, whether a cast really incurs any additional code at runtime is an implementation detail, but basically, it won't if it doesn't have to.